# How do I use a SOCKS proxy with npm got package?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, proxies

I'm using npm `got` package to do web scraping and I want to use a SOCKS proxy. The docs have this snippet about using proxies:

```
import got from 'got';
import {HttpsProxyAgent} from 'hpagent';

await got('https://sindresorhus.com', {
    agent: {
        https: new HttpsProxyAgent([skipped by me])
    }
});
```

So I've tried using `socks-proxy-agent`, but apparently the `agent` property of got only supports `http`, `https` and `http2` keys.

How do I make got use my SOCKS agent?